# nginx proxy - can I forward the same request to multiple backends?

Tags: nginx, proxy, http

How can I use a nginx proxy setup to forward the same incoming request to multiple backend servers? I do not want a load-balancing, I want to send the same request to both servers. Normally I would set up a message-broker/worker system, but maybe someone knows how to do some tricky things with nginx? Is it possible?

A client sends a request X to my nginx proxy server. The nginx server forwards the request X to both backend servers A and B.

There is no need to send a response from either server to the client, so I can always set a HTTP 200 OK reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a cgi-script in the language of your convenience, that returns the 200 and then sends two requests of its own.